# How to stop yellow and grey boxes on serial console during boot?

Tags: serial, pi-zero, serial-console

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspian Stretch. When it boots, it prints grey and yellow square characters to the serial console before displaying "Last login ..." and the login prompt. I already have the loglevel set to zero. I still want getty, just no kernel messages or squares.

The squares that print out:[image: The square that print]
cmdline.txt

> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=1cc521d8-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash loglevel=0 logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0